# How do I completely remove VirtualBox from Server 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, virtualbox, windows

I'm having network problems since I installed VirtualBox on a Windows Server 2008 R2 64 bits machine. I tested with iperf and the speed suddenly goes to zero for a couple of seconds once every 1 to 3 minutes. I tried between other computers on the LAN simultaneously and when it happens it's only on the server with VirtualBox installed. VirtualBox was never running, just installed.

I uninstalled VirtualBox with the Windows uninstall utility and the problem remained. I installed VirtualBox again and the ext-pack I had installed reappeared automagically with the host-only network I had created, those were never uninstalled!!!. 
So, I removed the host-only adapter manually, removed the ext-pack manually and them uninstall VirtualBox again. Also to make sure I deleted the windows\system32\drivers\VBox*.sys files, deleted the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\VBox* keys from the registry, deleted Oracle from the "Program Files" folder and also removed the advanced firewall rules that were named "Oracle VM something". I even installed the newest version of my network card drivers and I'm still having the problem.

Please, I don't want to reinstall Windows, how can I completely remove VirtualBox and its drivers or solve this????

Comment: This is a question to your question: Why wouldn't you just use Hyper-V?

Comment: I'll go for Linux and KVM for my VMs after solving this. I was trying different setups and wanted to move a VM that was running with VirtualBox on a Linux host.